# What's the correct way to convert from &str to OsStr?

Tags: rust

I'm working with [rust-fuse](https://github.com/zargony/rust-fuse), which takes mount options as a `&[&std::ffi::os_str::OsStr]`. It appears that I should be splitting my incoming comma-separated options string, which I'm doing like so:

```
mod fuse {
    use std::ffi::OsStr;

    pub fn mount(options: &[&OsStr]) {}
}

fn example(optstr: &str) {
    let mut options: &[&str] = &[];
    if optstr != "" {
        options = optstr.split(",").collect::<Vec<_>>().as_slice();
    }
    fuse::mount(options)
}
```

Which gives the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:12:17
   |
12 |     fuse::mount(options)
   |                 ^^^^^^^ expected struct `std::ffi::OsStr`, found str
   |
   = note: expected type `&[&std::ffi::OsStr]`
              found type `&[&str]`
```

I was under the impression that all `&str`s were also `OsStr`s, but I'm new to Rust, so I guess that's wrong.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use [`OsStr::new`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.OsStr.html#method.new):

```
use std::ffi::OsStr;

fn main() {
    let a_string: &str = "Hello world";
    let an_os_str: &OsStr = OsStr::new(a_string);
    println!("{:?}", an_os_str);
}
```

Note that the explicit type specification is not necessary, I'm just including it for educational purposes.

In your specific case:

```
let options: Vec<_> = optstr.split(",").map(OsStr::new).collect();
fuse::mount(&options)
```

It's actually rather rare to need to do this explicitly, however. Most of the time, functions accept a type that implements `AsRef<OsStr>`. This would allow you to pass more types without having to think about it. You may want to consider asking the maintainer or submitting a patch to the library to make it more generic.

Comment: @BogdanMart this code compiles fine on Windows 10 with Rust 1.42.0.

Comment: I'm really sorry for this. I was bit confused after struggling with the compiler at that time. And stack overflow don't allow me to retract my downvote when I realized that  I was wrong.
But I've asked my friend to upvote to compensate for my failure. Sorry again.